# NSMutablearray set to (null)?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

So i have two view controller in FirstViewController and SecondViewController

in FirstViewController

```
 NSMutableArray *array;
```

create a property for it and synthesised it

in SecondViewController

NSMutableArray *arraySecond;

create a property and synthesized it 
then I try to do something like this (after arraySecond is set to something like a b c d )

```
FirstViewController *FV = [[FirstViewController alloc]init];
FV.array = arraySecond;
[FV release];
```

I try to do that but when I try to print out the array from firstviewcontroller it is being set to (null) why is it doing that and what can i do to fix it?

Comment: How exactly do you do the synthesis?

Comment: @synthesis array; @synthesis arraySecond;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating an instance of `FirstViewController`, setting the value of `array` and then releasing that instance which will deallocate the object. So the entire effort is wasted. Since this is in the `SecondViewController`, I am assuming the `FirstViewController` exists by this time so you shouldn't be setting the `array` of a new instance of `FirstViewController` but try to pass it to the existing instance. Since you already have a property declared to share across the view controllers, we will make use of it.

Do this when instantiating the `SecondViewController` instance in `FirstViewController`,

```
SecondViewController * viewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];

self.array = [NSMutableArray array];
viewController.arraySecond = self.array;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
[viewController release];
```

Now the array is shared across the view controllers. Do not initialize the `arraySecond` property elsewhere so that both of them keep pointing to the same object and the changes your make to `arraySecond` are visible to the `FirstViewController` instance. After coming back to the `FirstViewController` instance, access the values you've added using `array` property.

Alternatives to object sharing are delegate mechanism and notifications. You can look into them too. For now, this should work.

Answer (score 1):

```
FirstViewController *FV = [[FirstViewController alloc]init];

secondViewController *SV = [[secondViewController alloc]init];

//here create secondArray

[FV SetArray:SV.arraySecond];
```

If you synthesized the arraySecond then `[self.arraySecond release];`

Comment: AFAIK Obj-C is case-sensitive, so you should mind you don't copy `SetArray` but instead use `setArray` (note the lowercase *s*).

Comment: I went [FV.array setArray:SV.arraySecond];

Comment: if u synthasize the array then u can use with dot syntax.otherwise u have to use like this.